# How to remove a file attribute with chattr on CentOS

Tags: linux, command-line, centos, file-permissions

I have file that has the immutable attribute:

```
----ia-------e--
```

And I try to remove the attribute with

```
chattr -i / chattr -a
```

but it's not working.
What would be the correct command?

Answer (score 3):

You need to run the command as a superuser in order to remove the immutable attribute. The `chattr` [Man Page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chattr) states the following:

> A file with the 'i' attribute cannot be modified: it cannot be deleted
>   or renamed, no link can be created to this file and no data can be
>   written to the file. Only the superuser or a process possessing the
>   CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability can set or clear this attribute.

So the correct command would be:

```
sudo chattr -i filetochange
```